# Removing FileVault2 key from memory on lid close

Tags: sleep-wake, filevault, encryption

I would like to know, how to remove FileVault2 keys from memory, when I close the lid on my Macbook pro 15" running Yosemite.

It works, when I leave the computer as it slowly goes into standby by itself (first lock-screen then the screensaver and then standby). I had manage to do this, with this classic command:

```
sudo pmset -a destroyfvkeyonstandby 1
```

But the problem is, that when I close the lid when the screen is just locked, or it isn't locked it, wouldn't destroy the keys. It just locks the screen.

Short version: I want to destroy FileVault2 keys when I close the laptop lid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the **destroyfvkeyonstandby** option, you also need to specify that pmset is setting **hibernatemode 25** for the power management options.

```
sudo pmset -a destroyfvkeyonstandby 1 hibernatemode 25
```

Setting both options ensures that the Mac in question will hibernate (where the contents of the RAM are written to disk) and also have the FileVault 2 key automatically removed from the saved RAM.

When the laptop is awakened from hibernation, you should see your account icon and a password blank at the FileVault 2 login screen, which would indicate that it had been asleep.

[image]

When this setting is set, you may run into some Power Nap-related issues. I have a post on that available from here:

[Power Nap, power management settings and FileVault 2](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/power-nap-power-management-settings-and-filevault-2/)

Comment: This is the correct answer 99% of the time. But sometimes I've found it to not work.

Comment: Comments on that blog say that this stopped working on High Sierra.